# get remote file size (without using Content-Length field)

Tags: php, curl

I need to get size of remote file without download. I use this code, but headers from some sites doesn't contain **Content-Length:** field. How can I get filesize in that cases?

```
$ch = curl_init("http://wordpress.org/latest.zip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$contentLength = 'unknown';
if (preg_match('/Content-Length: (\d+)/', $data, $matches)) {
  $contentLength = (int)$matches[1];
}
echo $contentLength;
```

this is result of echo $data;

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 10 Apr 2012 11:32:20 GMT
Content-Type: application/zip
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: private
Content-Description: File Transfer
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=wordpress-3.3.1.zip
Content-MD5: d6332c76ec09fdc13db412ca0b024df9
X-nc: EXPIRED luv 139
```

Comment: Could it be that the header is returned, but the name is in small caps 'content-length'? Or that there is whitespaces between the colon and the actual value.

Comment: `echo $data` to see the content and headers

Comment: @safarov, I added result of echo $data to question.

Comment: @artaskerov - This might be useful: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=641741

Answer (score 0):

If Content-Length header is not present, that means that file size is unknown. In your case you have Content-Disposition header, wich means that downloadable file is an attachment to server response (same as email attachment). So here if you have no Content-Length header you can't get the size.